# Generics on protocol

Tags: swift

I have this protocol:

```
protocol Addable
{
    mutating func addNumber(value: Int)
}
```

and this extension

```
extension Int : Addable
{
    mutating func addNumber(value: Int)
    {
        self = self + value
    }
}
```

This code:

```
    var number : Int = 10
    number.addNumber(10)
    println(number)
```

Correctly prints 20

Now I want to extend the protocol Addable to other types. If I understand correctly, I don't use Generics with protocol, but I use an associated type:

```
protocol Addable
{
    typealias AddableType
    mutating func addNumber(value: AddableType)
}
```

So now, `AddableType` means a generic type, and I can extend for example Float

```
extension Float : Addable
{
    mutating func addNumber(value: Float)
    {
        self = self + value
    }
}

    var another : Float = 10.5
    another.addNumber(10.1)
    println(another)
```

This prints 20.6

Now, I know that I can enforce the associated type to conform to a protocol

```
protocol Addable
{
    typealias AddableType : AProtocol, AnotherProtocol // ...
    mutating func addNumber(value: AddableType)
}
```

**But, and here it's the question, I cannot enforce the conformance to a Type or some types**

```
protocol Addable
{
    typealias AddableType : Int, Float
    mutating func addNumber(value: AddableType)
}

Error: Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Int'
Error: Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Float'
```

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a second protocol and implement that on the types that you want:

```
protocol AddableRequirement {}

extension Int: AddableRequirement {}
extension Float: AddableRequirement {}

protocol Addable {
    typealias AddableType: AddableRequirement
    mutating func addNumber(value: AddableType)
}
```

You also may want to use `Self` instead of a typealias:

```
protocol Addable {
    mutating func addNumber(value: Self)
}
```

That way, your protocol requires that the type always be addable with itself.

Comment: Good, I arrived to the same solution immediately after writing the question :-) Accepted because you are the first that answered. And because of the "Self" hint that is very useful. Thank you and to all other that answered

Answer (score 2):

You could define a new protocol and declare conformance for the types you want to allow.

```
protocol AllowedAddableType {}

extension Int: AllowedAddableType {}
extension Float: AllowedAddableType {}
// ...

protocol Addable
{
    typealias AddableType: AllowedAddableType
    mutating func addNumber(value: AddableType)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Types can conform to protocols, and protocols can conform to protocols, but protocols cannot conform to types. Having a protocol conform to a type doesn't make any sense within the grammatical definition of the language.

I'm guessing that your intention is to limit the types of objects that are allowed to conform to this protocol. In that case, you can define a protocol that **inherits** from a type, and then have your protocol conform to that protocol.

```
protocol TypeRestrictor {}

extension Int: TypeRestrictor {}
extension Float: TypeRestrictor {}

protocol Addable {
    typealias AddableType: TypeRestrictor
    mutating func addNumber(value: AddableType)
}
```